# UICollectionView one row for each section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to develop a component that allows the user to reserve a room selecting the starting hour and dragging to the final hour, in 15 minutes steps.
I'm thinking about using a UICollectionView but I need each section to scroll horizontally *at the same time*.

Each cell will have a label with the time, something like "00:00  00:15  00:30  00:45" and so on.
The best would be having these labels only on the top row.

I was thinking about using a table view with collection views inside the cells, but that would allow the user to scroll each collection view independently.

Any idea?

Edit: trying to explain better.

```
           00:00  |   00:15  |   00:30  |  00:45  |  01:00  |  01:15
Room 1     -------|----------|          |         |         |
Room 2            |          |          |         |         |
Room 3            |          |          |         |         |
```

In this example, Room 1 is reserved from 00:00 to 00:15. The problem of the selection will be solved later (I was just thinking of changing the background color of each selected cell).
Only one room can be selected, so if the user starts to select the time for Room 2, Room 1 loses its selection.
In this example, the Labels "Room 1", "Room 2" and "Room 3" are static, while the timeline is scrolling horizontally from 00:00 to 23:45 (using the 24h time).

Comment: I didn't fully understand how ur screen will look like. can you explain better or add an image?

Comment: Added an example, hoping it's clear enough.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter what view types you gonna use.  you will need to do tricky things. you can do table/collection or collection/table.

Comment: you need to handle 2 things. the dragging which can be solved like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390728/uicollectionview-drag-finger-over-cells-to-select-them/27391707

Comment: the other problem is the scrolling. which u need to implement the scrollviewdidscroll method detect the scrolling position then reload you table/collection and set scroll position for all to same value. this one is not that hard.

Comment: look like a gantt chart